# Validator Rule from addMethod always returning true

Tags: ajax, validation, email, exists

This is driving me nuts. Doing a simple check for whether or not an email address exists in my database via php using ajax in an addMethod rule to my validator. I've confirmed the php file is outputting "true" or "false" properly upon finding the email or not but the rule always returns true even though the response is correct and the value is false.

This is the rule:

```
 $.validator.addMethod("isExisting", function() {
    var checkemail=$("#email").val();
    console.log('Email: '+checkemail); // shows email populated correctly
    if(checkemail){
        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'checkemail.php',
        data: {email:checkemail,},
        success: function(response){

                console.log(response); // properly returns text "false" when email not found

                var exists = (response=="false") ? false : true;

                console.log('exists = '+exists); // is properly false

                return exists; // returns false
             }
        });
    }
});
```

And in the validator - 
(the "isExisting" error message *always* pops up regardless of whether the email really exists or not):

```
$("#signupform").validate({
         errorLabelContainer: "#errors",
         errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
         },
         rules: {
           fullname: {
               required: true,
               minlength: 2
                   },
           email: {
               required: true,
               email: true,
               isExisting: true
                   },
           areacode: {
               required: true,
               digits: true,
               minlength: 3
                   },
           prefix: {
               required: true,
               digits: true,
               minlength: 3
                   },
           num: {
               required: true,
               digits: true,
               minlength: 4
                   },
           address: {
               required: true,
                   },
           city: {
               required: true,
                 },
           noRobot: {
               isCaptcha: true,
           }
         },
         messages: {
           fullname: {
               required: "Please enter your full name.<br />",
               minlength: "Please enter your First and Last name.<br />"
                   },
           email: {
               required: "Please enter your email address.<br />",
               email: "Please enter a valid email address.<br />",
               isExisting: "There is already an account with that email address.<br />"
                   },
           areacode: {
               required: "Please enter your areacode.<br />",
               minlength: "Your areacode should be 3 digits. »XXX« XXX-XXXX<br />"
                  },
           prefix: {
               required: "Please enter your phone number prefix.<br />",
               minlength: "Your phone number Prefix should be 3 digits.  XXX »XXX«-XXXX<br />"
               },
           num: {
               required: "Please enter your phone number suffix.<br />",
               minlength: "Your phone number Suffix should be 4 digits. XXX XXX-»XXXX«<br />"
               },
           address: {
               required: "Please enter your Street Address for pick-up service.<br />"
                   },
           city: {
               required: "Please enter your town or city.<br />"
                   },
           noRobot: {
               isCaptcha: "Please verify that your are not a spam Robot.<br />"
                   }
         }
});
```

I would think the "isExisting: true" would only validate true if the true value was returned from the response. (scratches head in frustration...)

checkemail.php:

```
else{
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `customer_info` WHERE `email`='$email' LIMIT 1");
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($num > 0){
        echo "true";
    }
    else {
        echo "false";
    }
}
mysqli_close($connect);
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the validator methods should return true when the response is *valid*. In your case, the valid response is to not have a matching email, so you want to return true if the AJAX call returns false.

It would probably be less confusing to make this method *isUnused* rather than *isExisting* to avoid the boolean confusion, but you would need to change checkemail.php as well.

**Edit**: Disregard my answer above, I clearly misunderstood the problem.

I think the real issue is to do with asynchronous calls. Try setting *async: false* in your ajax call.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that before, but just to be sure I tried it again. Console then gives me the following error: ( jquery-3.2.0.min.js:9446 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. ) - and results are the same.